# Trouble with Angular/Ajax/PHP not getting the data

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

I'm having a simple problem that I cannot seem to resolve.  I'm trying to return a simple set of data from mysql database using angular/ajax and php.  The problem is nothing populates in the HTML.  No errors in debugger. Here is my code.

HTML:

```html
<?php
include("includes/header.php");
?>
<body ng-app="testapp">
  <div ng-ctrl="HomeController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <p>{{name}}</p>

    <ul ng-repeat="user in users">
      <li>{{user.fname user.lname}}</li>
    </ul>


  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/testapp.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/TestController.js"></script>
</body>
<?php
  include("includes/footer.php");
?>
```

ANGULAR/AJAX

```
    angular.module("testapp").controller("TestController", function($scope, $http){
      $scope.name = "";

      $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "../includes/getUsers.php"
      }).success(function(data){
        $scope.users = data;
      });

    });
```

Finally PHP getUsers.php:

```
  include("connection.php");

  $query = "SELECT fname, lname FROM user"

  $rows = $db->query($query);
  $data = array();
  while ($row = $rows->fetchAll(PDO:FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }


  echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: any error you are getting in console?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in the console in developer tools using chrome.

Comment: Why use `POST`?

Comment: share your `connection.php` code

Comment: add an error handler and find out what it tells you. Can also inspect actual request in browser dev tools for clues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ;)

This statement is causing problem:

```
while ($row = $rows->fetchAll(PDO:FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Here you are using constant `FETCH_ASSOC` of `PDO` class so replace `:` with `::`

```
while ($row = $rows->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

and one more thing always set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in development so that you can get all errors;

**UPDATE**

You should also add proper headers for JSON response also mentioned by @venkatesh-konatham:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @EricSchumann If this answer solved you issue then accept it and close question;

Comment: Sorry. Newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to call your php code to verify if it's returning something.

After that, try to add an .error() in the $http call to verify if really succeds the request

Comment: Verified that addUsers.php returns JSON string by including on index.php and echoing out to document.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is bind json data to angularjs. Can you try adding content type on your php code like below on the header

`header('Content-Type: application/json');`